# Showing multiple sidkekiq processes on sidekiq ui

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I have a single rails application setup of `app1` and `app2` (nginx,puma & sidekiq) with loadbalancer on `app1` (that is loadbalancing to nginx on `app1` and `app`2) and `db` server (postgres and redis). Sidekiq on `app1` & `app2` is both pointing to redis on `db`. I have sidekiq ui configured in the routes file like so:

`authenticate :admin, lambda { |a| a.admin? } do
    require 'sidetiq/web'
    mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
  end`

On my dev env that works fine but on production the loadbalancer route to either `app1` or `app2`. So looking at '/sidekiq' will only show process for that app server. I would like to see both processes (`app1` & `app2`) on the sidekiq ui. Any idea how that would be configured to show?

Answer (score -1):

go to `app1.yourdomail.com/sidekiq` for the webui of **app1 sidekiq**

go to `app2.yourdomain.com/sidekiq` for the webui of **app2 sidekiq**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In this case there is only one application and yourdomain.com points to load balancer on server app1 (not subdomain) that then load balances between nginx on server app1 and app2. So there is no app1 and app2 subdomains, load balancer will decide to which app server to route.